# how to set a FILE** variable to stdout?

Tags: c, mingw

Mockup of my production code:

```
/* version 1 */
#include <stdio.h>
FILE** fout = &stdout;
int main() {
     fprintf( *fout, "hello\n" );
}
```

Works fine under gcc, but reportedly fails to compile under mingw (lvalue required as unary '&' operand).

I have seen [Is setting a FILE* equal to stdout portable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12008516/1017348); I understand that

```
/* version 2 */
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* fout = stdout;
    fprintf( fout, "hello\n" );
}
```

would be perfectly valid. However, I need to preset a global variable. Unfortunately,

```
/* version 3 */
#include <stdio.h>
FILE* fout = stdout;
int main() {
    fprintf( fout, "hello\n" );
}
```

is not suitable to replace version 1; it does not even compile under gcc (line 2: initializer element is not constant).

Any idea how to get stdout into a variable that is initialized before main() starts?

Comment: The Stdout stream is already opened! There cannot be 2 stdout open at the same time... I suggest maybe using the #define, or simply let main start then store it into a global var.. Why before main starts?

Comment: Why before main starts: as author of a library, I offer my users a `struct default_settings` that is initialized in the library code, and that shall contain `fout=stdout` among many other parameter settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux (glibc), `stdout` is defined like this:

```
extern struct _IO_FILE *stdout;
```

So, you can do whatever you need with that.

However, on MinGW, `stdout` is defined like this, in `stdio.h`:

```
#define stdout  (&_iob[STDOUT_FILENO])
```

Alas, that's not something you can take the address of, and, as you discovered, it's not something you can use in a global initializer. :-(

The root of the problem is that the C standard says that these should be macros, which means any portable program should make no assumptions about what's inside. So, I'm afraid, there is no easy way to avoid doing reading `stdout` programmatically. This sort of thing is why many libraries require a `lib_initialize()` function that must be called before anything else.

C++ does permit constructors for global variables, and these are automatically called before `main`, even for libraries. It is possible, with `gcc`, to hack a C program to do the same, but that's an evil trick and I can't remember how to do it off the top of my head.

I'd just do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE* fout = NULL;

int my_library_function() {
    if (!fout)
      fout = stdout;
    fprintf( fout, "hello\n" );
}
```

That isn't a big efficiency problem: you'd have to load `fout` anyway, and a compare with zero is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (7.21.1), `stdout` is a macro which is an expression of type "pointer to FILE".  It is not necessarily a global variable.  It is not portable C to take its address --- it works in gcc but not in mingw, as you saw.

Use the second version of your code --- this is portable.

The third would be OK too if you moved the **initialization** of `fout` inside `main`:

```
/* version 3 */
#include <stdio.h>
FILE* fout;
int main() {
    fout = stdout;
    fprintf( fout, "hello\n" );
}
```

This initialization cannot be combined with the declaration of `fout`, as `stdout` is not (at least, not necessarily) a constant expression.

If you want to have a `FILE **` pointer, use:

```
/* version 4 */
#include <stdio.h>
FILE* mystdout;
FILE** fout = &mystdout;
int main() {
     mystdout = stdout;
     fprintf( *fout, "hello\n" );
}
```

but again the initialization of `mystdout` cannot be at its declaration, for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks for the link and for the explanation. However "Use any of the other two versions of your code --- these are portable" - this I cannot confirm; as I wrote, my version 3 fails to compile. I do not care whether `fout` is of type `FILE*` or `FILE**`. What matters for me is that users of my library should get `fout=stdout` by default; they should not be requested to insert a line like `fout=stdout` in their code; this should be done by default initialization before main() starts.

Comment: Right, version 3 requires that the global variable be initialized inside `main`, as I wrote in my answer.  I'm editing.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke Then why don't you simply use a global variable visible externally? Then users could just write `globalFile = some_other_file;` conveniently.

Comment: @H2CO3 Indeed, I am trying to use a global variable; see my versions 1 and 3. The question is how to initialize it inside my library, hence before main starts.

Comment: Variable `mystdout` is global; its declaration is visible externally. But it cannot be **initialized** together with its declaration, as the expression `stdout` that you want to initialize it with is not a constant expression.  This, you need to do in `main` (or some other place of your code).  Of course you can assign anything else you like to `mystdout` at any time.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke, I'm afraid you cannot initialize it **before** `main` starts, you will have to do it **just when** main `starts`.  Why is that a problem?

Comment: @nickie To encapsulate default initialization in a library.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke, I can see two options: 1) You could have an `initMyLibrary` function. 2) You  could initialize it with `NULL` and re-initialize it on demand when it was first used.  If both are unacceptable, start a question about library initialization, this is a more general problem.  The issue here is that `stdout` is not (necessarily) known at compile/link time.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke, would it be acceptable to play with file descriptors?  These are integers and `stdout` corresponds to 1, therefore a global initialization would work.

Comment: @nickie I like your idea of having a NULL-initialized something that gets overwritten when it is first used. Concerning file descriptors: why not? Could you possibly elaborate that into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is a very good idea, as file descriptors are not generally portable.  Also, it makes the implementation of library functions quite low-level, or you'll have a hard time synchronizing file descriptors and `FILE` pointers.

However, as @JoachimWuttke explicitly asked, here's what I had in mind in my previous comment:

```
/* version 5 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fdout = 1;

void use(FILE *fout)
{
  fdout = fileno(fout);
}

void printing() {
  const char msg[] = "hello\n";
  write(fdout, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
}

int main() {
  printing(); // this one goes to stdout
  FILE *f = fopen("output.txt", "wt");
  use(f);
  printing(); // this one goes to "output.txt"
  printing(); // this one too
  fclose(f);
  use(stdout);
  printing(); // this one goes to stdout too
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @nickie. The first answer that makes initialization as easy as I had in mind - but on the expense of having `fprintf` replaced by `write`. I fear I am not willing to pay this price. So I submit to the insight that there is no easy and clean solution.

Comment: `FILE* fp_ = fdopen(fdout, "w");` -- not elegant in this context