# directing file output to the console

Tags: c, file, console

I'm working with a C-function `foo(FILE* file)` that outputs some text to a file.

Rather than write to a .txt file, I'd like `foo` to write to the console.

Is there a way to pass 'the console' as a FILE*? (And if so, how) ?

(`foo` is part of a library and I can't edit the source code directly)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505530/how-to-set-a-file-variable-to-stdout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a special file object called `stdout` that will write to the console (assuming the shell didn't redirect anything).

```
foo(stdout);
```